# Why does css get installed when I run npm install [someLibraryName]?

Tags: css, vue.js, npm, webpack, vue-material

When I run this command...

```
npm install vue-material
```

It seemed to install and override some css in my application causing css conflicts. I had to search and find the exact piece of css and override it directly on the specific vue component's  section.

Is there anyway to prevent this from happening when installnig NPM packages?

Technologies uses:

- vue.js
- webpack
- material-vue

Comment: [Vue Material](https://vuematerial.io/) appears to be a set of styled components for use with the Vue framework. How else should a component library style things than with CSS? It's really on you to do your research before installing an NPM package to ensure it's what you want...

Comment: Just installing npm packages will not override your styling without you including that package somewhere in your app. Also, most of the frameworks will come with their own set of classes, so if you use that framework, you need to make sure that your naming convention for classes does not collide with framework. If you need to customize theme, you can look at the [Creating themes docs](https://vuematerial.io/themes/configuration)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I guess I don't understand how npm install X package includes it's own CSS globally in my project? Where does it get referenced?

Comment: @ljubadr okay, well if I include the vue-material css on a vue component in my application that has not been rendered yet, why should this importing of css on a non-rendered component override css on another component? Let me know if that makes sense

Comment: Did you follow steps from [Getting started](https://vuematerial.io/getting-started)? Did you add `import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css'` at any point?

Comment: @ljubadr  yeah I did, but this component hadn't been rendered yet, I'm not sure if that matters. I guess there might be a way to only include the css needed for a specific component instead of including the WHOLE css bundle for material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found out what I was looking for thank you @ljubadr for your help.

In the recommended [Getting Started](https://vuematerial.io/getting-started) vue material guide it states you can:

```
import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css'
```

However, if you only need one component, this should work for a specific CSS need on a specific vue component:

```
import 'vue-material/dist/Components/MdCard/index.css'
```

Comment: I'm glad you found solution for this